# can not send existing objects using serialization android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, serializable

I'm trying to transfer an object from one activity to another using intent and serialization android. here i'm not able to send already existing objects(received as null) but when sending new object it works properly.

here's the snippet :

```
private void someMethod(TPackage tpackageObj) {
Intent intent = new Intent(obj, my.tatasky.ChannelActivity.class);      
intent.putExtra("parcel", new TPackage()); // it works
intent.putExtra("parcel", tpackageObj); // doesn't work
}
```

Comment: how you are calling this method? and i think we use putParcebleExtra instead of just putExtra

Comment: Can you post the class you're trying to send? It might have something to do with a non-Serializable class member being initialized in your existing object that isn't initialized in your newly constructed object.

Comment: when it works means object is transferred and retrieved at receiver side as desired but and "it doesnt work" means object(newly created) is retrieved as null at receiver side.

Comment: Do your tpackageObj object contain some attribute with non-Serializable instance ?

Comment: got a technique, i'm creating new object from older object values which are initialized in constructor, and it worked fine!! thnaks :)

Answer (score 0):

your custom class implement Serializable interface and then you can pass object instances in intent extra using putExtra(Serializable..) variant of the Intent#putExtra() method.

PSEUDO code:

//to pass :
   intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);

// to retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");